# Fetch and dispatch in a redux action function

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx

In my react/redux project, I call a function from my action to fetch a data from an api. Fetch starts the api request... but react doesn't recognize dispatch()

```
function getAuthenticatedUser() {
    ....

    return fetch("my.api/path", requestHeaders)
                .then(response => handleResponse(response))
                .then(response=>{
                    return response.json()
                }).then(responseJson =>{
                    dispatch(requestSuccess(responseJson.user))
                })

....
function requestSuccess(....
....
```

Then, I wrapped around **return dispatch** as follows. Now it outputs no error, but fetch() doesn't start any api requests. (No requests in Network/XHR)

```
return dispatch => {
            return fetch("my.api/path", requestHeaders)
                .then(response => handleResponse(response))
                .then(response=>{
                    return response.json()
                }).then(responseJson =>{
                    dispatch(requestSuccess(responseJson.user))
                })
        }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you `console.log()`ed right before the dispatch, to confirm it's getting there. Additionally, try `console.log(dispatch)`. Is it a function? `console.log(requestSuccess(responseJson.user))`. Does it return an object with a type/payload? After this, you need to check your reducer. Make sure dispatch is properly handled/captured.

Comment: are you using redux-thunk or some other middleware to handle the returned function? Seems like in the second attempt the returned function isn't being run.

Comment: Where and how are you using this action function? You need to provide a [mcve] as there are lots of ways to dispatch actions!

Comment: I want to thank you all. I am a beginner in React redux and I successfully completed my first fetch. I added an answer related with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Firstly I want to thanks to 3 comments on the question.

I firstly installed redux-thunk. I added a middleware to my store:

```
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
...
export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Than, I imported store in my component and dispatched my action function. (Previously I was calling it directly)

```
constructor(props) {
    ....
    store.dispatch(userActions.getAuthenticatedUser())
```

Now fetch and dispatchers within fetch work fine.